# Java: Get USB Mass Storage Device Information

Tags: java, windows, usb, libusb, usb4java

is there a possibility to get USB mass storage information like the serial of an USB device in Java on Windows?

I tried to achieve that with USB4Java (low and high-level API) and it works, but the problem is that I have to install a customized driver to get access to the information from my Java app (described in the FAQ at http://usb4java.org/). When that special driver (created with Zadig) is installed I don't have any further access to the device from the Windows explorer (just from my Java app).

I would like to detect when a new USB device is attached and if it was attached, I would like to get some information like the serial number of the device, the device name, the drive letter that was assigned etc.

That app should be used by other users and I couldn't force them to create a customized driver for each device ...
Do you have any hints how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Edit: Is it possible to get the usb-port of a connected device with Java-built-in methods? 
I've tried sth with `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemDisplayName()` but there are no such options. Is there another possibility to get vendor id's or sth. similiar with Java?

Or is it possible to get the drive letter with USB4Java?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to see if you can discover sufficient information by working through the windows file system information, volume management, or whatever APIs.  Doing an end run around that by talking USB Mass Storage operations yourself does sound like an installation and exclusion nightmare, unless you can somehow claim the device first, then release it to the OS to mount (which seems tricky, and still suffers the custom installation problem).